# Is there an SQL Clause to check if all multiple Values exists instead of using multiple AND?

Tags: mysql, sql

Instead of typing

`... WHERE transaction = 1 AND transaction = 2 AND transaction = 3 AND transaction = 4 AND transaction = 5`

Is there any `Clause` to check it once In one simple set like this?

`... WHERE transaction HAS(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Comment: aid cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You're probably thinking of `aid IN (1,2,3,4,5)`?

Comment: transaction cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time, so the query presented doesn't make any sense

Comment: I agree with the others.  `transaction` can't be `1` and `2`.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Did you mean `OR` instead of `AND`?  Are you trying to verify that all the specified values of `transaction` exist?

Comment: @BaconBits Yes, I'm trying to verify that all specified values exists.

Comment: In that case something like @GordonLinoff's answer will work.

Comment: Please provide an mcve. It is not clear what exactly you are asking

Comment: @NineBerry I'm trying to check if there is a row in my table that has the multiple existence of transaction(1, 2, 3) from normalized secondary table, Just like `user1` has `transactions(1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT name
FROM table
WHERE aid IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT aid) = 5;
```

Comment: Would it be more efficient and faster query , Or do you recommend to stick with `AND . AND . AND`

Comment: @Toleo . . . You should use `IN` because it is the correct logic.